# strings are throwing errors

Tags: python

In this project I am checking the number is even or odd with the help of user input. The problem I am stuck on is that when the user types a str character the whole project blows up. I want to write a program where even if the user typed a string the program won't blow up would print("Please type a number") a message like that.

```
type num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if num % 2 == 0:
  print(str(num) + ' is an even number')
else:
  print(str(num) + ' is an odd number')
```

I tried try and except and even functions but I couldn't provide a logic to run the program.

Comment: what is that `type` at the beggining?

Comment: you can either use a `elseif` or [try and except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Comment: @matszwecja that was a typo

Comment: @Shad0w yeah i tried it with try and except its works thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `type`at the beginning, but this may help you:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please type a number.')
        continue
    
if num % 2 == 0:
    print(str(num) + ' is an even number')
else:
    print(str(num) + ' is an odd number')
```

Comment: That "type" at the beginning was a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. But one thing I didn't understand is why did you use while loop and why is it set to "True"

Comment: `while True` loop will keep on running forever until it encounters `break` statement (because there is no way for the while condition to be False) - so the code will keep on asking for a number until no ValueError is raised.